# PyQT6, no tooltip being displayed on button click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm new to python and following this tutorial:

```
https://zetcode.com/pyqt6/firstprograms/
```

Based on the tutorial, I'm trying to use PyQT6 to create a simple window with a button:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt6.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()


def main():
    print(QT_VERSION_STR)
    print(PYQT_VERSION_STR)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The window and button pop up for me, but nothing happens when I click on it, no tooltips or anything. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip does show with the code you have.

To make the tooltip pop-up hover over the button for a few seconds.

Comment: lol I thought the tooltip appears if you click the button, thanks for the clear up!